# How to change the macro value before comipling using Make or CMake?

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, c-preprocessor

I was searching for some way to change the macro values. I want to use macro values like user-friendly variables. Like we used the `scanf` function and store the user input to a variable.

If this way is not possible then Can we use the CMake or make to do this? If yes then how?

Example.

header. h

```
#define LED  8
```

I want to change this value before compile. Is there any way we can do that?

Please explain in detail. So I can understand perfectly. Possible add some example or link of example.

Thanks.

Comment: You could wrap all affected macros in `#ifndef XY #define XY 123 #endif` blocks and provide a value via `-DXY=234` command line option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a compilation flag `-DLED=8` where you replace the `8` with whatever value you want.

You should also wrap the LED macro with

```
#ifndef LED
#define LED 8
#endif
```

This way, the `-DLED=X` will define the macro as X and, since it's already defined, the header file won't try to redefine it.

Regarding CMake, try adding `add_compile_definitions(LED=8)`. Check [this](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) for more info.

Comment: Can you show me how to add the -DLED in the CMake file and how I can the value. As you explain I think I need to write this line in the CMake file. Right? Can we pass the value using the command line or some other way?

Comment: Try adding this: `add_compile_definitions(LED=8)`

Comment: Check this for more info: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html

Comment: Better to use `target_compile_definitions` - see example here -> https://dev.to/iblancasa/learning-cmake-2-43ga

Comment: Can you tell me how we do the same thing in using make file. I found code -> `CFLAGS= -DLED_GPIO=\$(LED_GPIO)` I put this is code in components.mk file which works the same as making a file. But this does now work. Is there any way we provide the value at command line like `-DFLAG=15`,